# Haskell's (<-) in Terms of the Natural Transformations of Monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, syntactic-sugar, comonad

So I'm playing around with the hasbolt module in GHCi and I had a curiosity about some desugaring. I've been connecting to a Neo4j database by creating a pipe as follows

```
ghci> pipe <- connect $ def {credentials}
```

and that works just fine. However, I'm wondering what the type of the `(<-)` operator is (GHCi won't tell me). Most desugaring explanations describe that

```
do x <- a
   return x
```

desugars to

```
a >>= (\x -> return x)
```

but what about just the line `x <- a`?
It doesn't help me to add in the `return` because I want `pipe :: Pipe` not `pipe :: Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m => m Pipe`, but `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` so trying to desugar using `bind` and `return`/`pure` doesn't work without it.

Ideally it seems like it'd be best to just make a `Comonad` instance to enable using `extract :: Monad m => m a -> a` as `pipe = extract $ connect $ def {creds}` but it bugs me that I don't understand `(<-)`.

Another oddity is that, treating `(<-)` as haskell function, it's first argument is an out-of-scope variable, but that wouldn't mean that

```
(<-) :: a -> m b -> b
```

because not just anything can be used as a free variable. For instance, you couldn't bind the pipe to a `Num` type or a `Bool`. The variable has to be a "String"ish thing, except it never is actually a `String`; and you definitely can't try actually binding to a `String`. So it seems as if it isn't a haskell function in the usual sense (unless there is a class of functions that take values from the free variable namespace... unlikely). So what is `(<-)` exactly? Can it be replaced entirely by using `extract`? Is that the best way to desugar/circumvent it?

Comment: Further, despite my referring to it as `(<-)` throughout the question; you can't actually use it as a prefix operator like that...

Comment: `<-` is not a function at all, it is a part of Haskell’s *syntax*. Specifically, it is specially recognized by the parser as part of `do` blocks.

Comment: As Alexis King says `(<-)` is not a function; it is just syntax sugar. In `do { x <- m; f x }`, you can't meaningfully separate the `<-` from the `;`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm wondering what the type of the (<-) operator is ...

`<-` doesn't have a type, it's part of the syntax of `do` notation, which as you know is converted to sequences of `>>=` and `return` during a process called desugaring.

> but what about just the line x <- a ...?

That's a syntax error in normal haskell code and the compiler would complain. The reason the line:

```
ghci> pipe <- connect $ def {credentials}
```

works in ghci is that the repl is a sort of `do` block; you can think of each entry as a line in your `main` function (it's a bit more hairy than that, but that's a good approximation). That's why you need (until recently) to say `let foo = bar` in ghci to declare a binding as well.

Comment: Indeed, so if I want to do without that symbol, is `Comonad` the only/best way or are there other/better ways?

Comment: @Tshimanga `do` notation is *just sugar*. You can rewrite *any* `do` block using `>>=`, `>>`, lambdas, and `let`. You could use the unsugared syntax if you’d like.

Comment: @AlexisKing, then what does `x <- a` desugar to? I'm inclined to believe @jberryman and @duplode in that, on it's own, it doesn't actually represent a proper expression outside of the GHCi execution enviornment. I have tried `(connect $ def {creds}) >>= (\pipe ->return pipe)` and the line runs in GHCi without error, but it tosses the resulting `m Pipe` (which isn't what I want anyways) out into the ether without a handle haha

Comment: GHCi operates in IO, which is why you can do stuff like `print 123` and it prints 123. So you can use `str <- getLine`, and it'll wait for you to put in a line, and then it'll bind `str` to the result.

Comment: @Tshimanga and `Comonad` has nothing to do with this. You'd be better off forgetting comonads are even a thing until long after you've completely understood monads (and applicatives, and transformers, and lenses, and categories, and...)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I only suggested that `extract` would be an alternative method of unpackaging monads that doesn't really on the syntactic sugar of `do`-notation. I'm by no means married to the idea of making heavy use of `Comonad`, nor am I suggesting a deeper connection than "this also does the job". If you have a third alternative (that is, neither sugar nor `Comonad`) to offer, I'm always open to learning something new

Comment: @Tshimanga `x <- a` cannot desugar to anything in isolation because `x <- a` is only valid inside a larger `do` block. It would be like asking what `(3 +` means—it is not a valid expression. However, *any* valid `do` block **can** be converted to code without `do` notation. For example, `do { x <- a; return x }` is desugared to `a >>= (\x -> return x)` (though that is redundant, since it’s precisely equivalent to `a` by the monad laws).

Comment: @AlexisKing indeed, and happens to be my point in the last comment I directed to you. All that said, while saying that it "desugars" to it certainly seems a touch too strong a statement, `extract` would seem to offer a suitable alternative in accomplishing the same task. What do you think?

Comment: @Tshimanga But it ***does*** desugar to that. What you seem to be misunderstanding is that is **literally** how GHC compiles `do` blocks. They get converted to uses of `>>=` and `>>` as a compilation step, I believe before GHC generates core. `do` blocks are macros, they are syntactic sugar, they are shorthand syntax, and they specifically work with monads (`RebindableSyntax` aside). Saying “desugars” is too strong is not true, since it ***literally does*** desugar.

Comment: @AlexisKing, i meant too strong to say it desugars to `extract`. I'm aware of how `do` blocks are translated into the natural transformations by the compiler. Initially, my curiosity was about what I should probably call an incomplete segment of a `do` block (GHCi was completing it for me). Now I just want to explore other ways of unpacking monads

Comment: @Tshimanga I think we all misinterpreted your question a little. What might be helpful is to observe that `a <- x` doesn't actually "extract" a value. What `Monad` gives you is _composition_ (`(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`); we can never pull a value of type `a` or `b` out of one of those `m a` or `m b` (except for certain _concrete_ `m`); indeed this "limitation" is what allows haskell to use monads to accomplish `IO` while maintaining purity. All this is what I think @BenjaminHodgson is getting at when he suggests you have more studying to do to fully grok Monad

Comment: More concretely, most things that are instances of `Monad` have no possible law-abiding `Comonad` instance, so you can't expect to use `extract` on them.

Comment: @jberryman yeah I think my initial confusion stemmed from that when I typed `a <- x` in GHCi, it actually returned to me an unpacked pipe. This made me think that in general `a <- x` did some unpacking, despite knowing that the natural transformations of a monad can't actually do that. Maybe I thought there was some caveat in Haskell that made things not quite like the category theoretic concepts I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Tshimanga Everything entered into GHCi is effectively inside one big `IO` `do` block, which is why that syntax works in the REPL. When you used `a <- x` in the REPL, you are using the `>>=` operation of `IO`. The type of `connect` has a `MonadIO` constraint. Comonads and `extract` are not being used anywhere.

Comment: @AlexisKing I wasn't making the claim that `Comonad`s or `extract` were lurking under anywhere the hood. Just saying that since `a <- x` *as typed into the REPL* isn't a valid expression, I might be better disciplined to use another approach that doesn't depend on GHCi covering the rest. The type signature of `extract` suggested the possibility that I might use that instead to write something that not only executed as desired in the REPL but also represent valid code on it's own *as written*.

Comment: @AlexisKing again, I never was making the claim that there was a fundamental link between `do` and `Comonad`. Merely entertaining the idea of whether or not there could be an opportunistic way to implement `extract` to do the same process in this specific situation.

Answer (score 4):

> Ideally it seems like it'd be best to just make a Comonad instance to enable using extract :: Monad m => m a -> a as pipe = extract $ connect $ def {creds} but it bugs me that I don't understand (<-).

Comonad has nothing to do with Monads. In fact, most Monads don't have any valid Comonad instance. Consider the `[]` Monad:

```
instance Monad [a] where
  return x = [x]
  xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

If we try to write a Comonad instance, we can't define `extract :: m a -> a`

```
instance Comonad [a] where
  extract (x:_) = x
  extract [] = ???
```

This tells us something interesting about Monads, namely that we can't write a general function with the type `Monad m => m a -> a`. In other words, we can't "extract" a value from a Monad without additional knowledge about it.

So how does the do-notation syntax `do {x <- [1,2,3]; return [x,x]}` work?

Since `<-` is actually just syntax sugar, just like how `[1,2,3]` actually means `1 : 2 : 3 : []`, the above expression actually means `[1,2,3] >>= (\x -> return [x,x])`, which in turn evaluates to `concat (map (\x -> [[x,x]]) [1,2,3]))`, which comes out to `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`.

Notice how the arrow transformed into a `>>=` and a lambda. This uses only built-in (in the typeclass) Monad functions, so it works for any Monad in general.

We can pretend to extract a value by using `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` and working with the "extracted" `a` inside the function we provide, like in the lambda in the list example above. However, it is impossible to actually get a value out of a Monad in a generic way, which is why the return type of `>>=` is `m b` (in the Monad)

Comment: yes, i know. im not trying to create `comonad` instances for `monad`s in general. that'd be a silly short-lived endeavour. i was entertaining whether there it was possible to create a `comonad` instance to leverage for this specific scenario in particular. to my knowledge, while it's true that **most** `monad`s don't support a `comonad`, I have not encountered the statement that **no** `monad`s can implement `comonad` instances

Answer (score 2):

> So what is `(<-)` exactly? Can it be replaced entirely by using `extract`? Is that the best way to desugar/circumvent it?

Note that the do-block `<-` and `extract` mean very different things even for types that have both `Monad` and `Comonad` instances. For instance, consider [non-empty lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html). They have instances of both `Monad` (which is very much like the usual one for lists) and `Comonad` (with `extend`/`=>>` applying a function to all suffixes of the list). If we write a do-block such as...

```
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as N
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..))
import Data.Function ((&))

alternating :: NonEmpty Integer
alternating = do
    x <- N.fromList [1..6]
    -x :| [x]
```

... the `x` in `x <- N.fromList [1..6]` stands for the elements of the non-empty list; however, this `x` *must* be used to build a new list (or, more generally, to set up a new monadic computation). That, as others have explained, reflects how do-notation is desugared. It becomes easier to see if we make the desugared code look like the original one:

```
alternating :: NonEmpty Integer
alternating =
    N.fromList [1..6] >>= \x ->
    -x :| [x]
```

```
GHCi> alternating
-1 :| [1,-2,2,-3,3,-4,4,-5,5,-6,6]
```

The lines below `x <- N.fromList [1..6]` in the do-block amount to the body of a lambda. `x <-` in isolation is therefore akin to a lambda without body, which is not a meaningful thing.

Another important thing to note is that `x` in the do-block above does not correspond to any one single `Integer`, but rather to *all* `Integer`s in the list. That already gives away that `<-` does not correspond to an extraction function. (With other monads, the `x` might even correspond to no values at all, as in `x <- Nothing` or `x <- []`. See also [Lazersmoke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42987648/2751851).)

On the other hand, `extract` does extract a single value, with no ifs or buts...

```
GHCi> extract (N.fromList [1..6])
1
```

... however, it is really a *single* value: the tail of the list is discarded. If we want to use the suffixes of the list, we need `extend`/`(=>>)`...

```
GHCi> N.fromList [1..6] =>> product =>> sum
1956 :| [1236,516,156,36,6]
```

If we had a co-do-notation for comonads (cf. [this package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/codo-notation) and the links therein), the example above might get rewritten as something in the vein of:

```
-- codo introduces a function: x & f = f x
N.fromList [1..6] & codo xs -> do
    ys <- product xs
    sum ys
```

The statements would correspond to plain values; the bound variables (`xs` and `ys`), to comonadic values (in this case, to list suffixes). That is exactly the opposite of what we have with monadic do-blocks. All in all, as far as your question is concerned, switching to comonads just swaps which things we can't refer to outside of the context of a computation.